Error Running Package (.deb) on Linux (dependency is not satisfiable: libffi7)
I downloaded a package I wanted to install, but during installation, the system returned an error: dependency is not satisfiable: libffi7. I assume this is because I have a newer version of Linux where libffi7 is no longer supported.
How can I resolve this issue? What should I do to install a package that requires libffi7, or is there a way to use a newer version of libffi instead, if possible?
I try to solve it like this: sudo apt-get install -f but it's does't work!
when I try to enter the command sudo dpkg -i SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb through the terminal. I got this:
Selecting previously unselected package scenebuilder.
(Reading database ... 738809 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb ...
Unpacking scenebuilder (23.0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scenebuilder:
 scenebuilder depends on libffi7; however:
  Package libffi7 is not installed.
 scenebuilder depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0; however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.
 scenebuilder depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scenebuilder (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scenebuilder

I also try sudo apt install ./SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb and i got:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'scenebuilder' instead of './SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 scenebuilder : Depends: libffi7 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


you need to install packages using apt-get install, so that they pull in their dependencies; dpkg -i is only useful if you've already installed all dependencies. As an end-user, you should basically never have to run dpkg yourself.
So, in your case, sudo apt-get install ./SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb. If that fails due to missing dependencies, the software you're trying to install from the .deb file is simply not compatible with your operating system.

or is there a way to use a newer version of libffi instead, if possible?

Here specifically, it would seem scenebuilder needs to be rebuild against the the libffi8 package.

can u see my edited question. If i got this error it's mean .deb file is simply not compatible with your operating system?

yes, that's why I explicitly wrote that.

do you think there is my package with libffi8? It seems to be from Java

I answered this is in my answer already.

this package is only available on the official website. I can't download it anywhere else. Others have the same system, but they install this package

no, they don't. It's clear that this isn't possible.

hmmmm... are u shure?

I will not, for the third time, repeat what I already wrote in my answer.
